# Angular js : Directive Accordion Button

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I could not put the button after the title in my accordion  using Angular js, how can I do that please in my template directive: have you an idea please.

css :

```
.StyleButton {
    float : left !important;
    color: @mBlueLight !important;
    background-color: @mWhite;
    padding-left : 10px;
    padding-right :10px;
    margin-top :-3px;
    margin-right :10px;
    &:hover{
        color:@mWhite;
    }
}

.directive('spotcam', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        require: '^accordion',
        scope: { title: '@' },
        template: '<div>' + 
                  ' <div class="title" ng-class="{true: \'selectedAccordionStyle\',false:\'\'}[showMe]"> <a class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus" ng-class="{true: \'glyphicon glyphicon-minus\', false:\'glyphicon glyphicon-plus\'}[showMe]" data-ng-click="toggle()"></a>  {{title}} <button class="StyleButton"> Valider la saisie</button> </div>' +
                   '<div class="body" data-ng-show="showMe" data-ng-transclude=""></div>' +
                   '</div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, accordionController) {
            scope.showMe = false;
            accordionController.addSpot(scope);
            scope.toggle = function () {
                scope.showMe = !scope.showMe;
                accordionController.Open(scope);
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: ... I must be missing something... Why to you have that `float: left` attribute on the button style if you don't want the button to be on the left of the title?

Comment: i have  the title and the button in the left of my accordion  and i want make the button after the title in my accordion all in the left :)